# setTimeout Jquery help

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

how can i settimeOut of 1 sec, for the following animation to take place, i tried using SetTimeout, but it didnt work, heres the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.caption_logo .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
$('.caption_logo .active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "-350px"}, 500);

var intval = setInterval(changeText, 300);    

function changeText(){
    var $activeText = $(".caption_logo .active-text");

    var $nextText = $activeText.next();
    if($activeText.next().length == 0) clearInterval(intval);

    $nextText.css({opacity: 0}).addClass('active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "-350px"}, 500, function(){

    $activeText.removeClass('active-text');                                           
    });
}
});
```

Comment: setTimeout is the fight function to use. Perhaps worth putting it in jsFiddle so we can see what the problem is?

Comment: where did u saye ,u used SetTimeout ?
i can't find it in the code

Comment: `setTimeout` will invoke your code only once, you are using `setInterval` and it will invoke your code every 300 ms. If you need to increase it: `setInterval(changeText, 1000); `.

Comment: Thats because you are waiting for the code to on windows ready, then your time out kicks in, unless it didnt work at all

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with setTimeout function like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.caption_logo .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
    $('.caption_logo .active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "-350px"}, 500);

    setTimeout(changeText, 300);    

    function changeText(){
        var $activeText = $(".caption_logo .active-text");

        var $nextText = $activeText.next();

        if($activeText.next().length > 0) setTimeout(changeText, 300);

        $nextText.css({opacity: 0}).addClass('active-text').animate(
            {
                opacity:1, 
                marginLeft: "-350px"
            }, 
            500, 
            function(){
                $activeText.removeClass('active-text');                                           
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Hope it work for you.